# Arabic invoice pdf issue Magento 2.4.5 showing as Arabic letters but not correct

Tags: invoice, pdf, arabic

Preconditions (*)

Magento 2.4.5[image]-develop
The store should be in Arabic
Steps to reproduce (*)

```
Place an order in Arabic store
Customer fill the address and name all in Arabic
Login to the admin panel and open orders
Create an invoice against the order
Download the invoice pdf and compare the content in the admin side with the invoice pdf
```

Comment: This issue was reported on Magento Github repository but it has not yet been resolved. You can follow it at https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/31363